# `markdown.extensions.def_list` not rendering correctly

Tags: markdown, lektor

I tried inserting a definition list in my contents.lr file.

Tables are working fine but the definition lists are not handled correctly.

**Example** taken from https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/index.html

```
Apple
:   Pomaceous fruit of plants of the genus Malus in
    the family Rosaceae.
Orange
:   The fruit of an evergreen tree of the genus Citrus.
```

Rendering the string directly with `markdown` works:

```
markdown.markdown(s, extensions=['markdown.extensions.def_list'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it documented anywhere, but with a quick look at the source code, it [appears](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/blob/master/setup.py#L25) that Lektor uses the [Mistune](http://mistune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Markdown parser, which does **not** support definition lists.

I'd suggest filing a bug report with Lektor, asking them to document what Markdown features they support and how to alter them.